# Trial Division faster than Sieve for Primality Test?

Tags: python, primality-test

I wrote two primality tests in python. First one is based on trial division, the second one applies sieve of Eratosthenes. My understanding is that sieve should have a smaller time complexity than trial, so sieve should be asymptotically faster.

However when I run it, trial division is much faster. For example, when `n = 6*(10**11)`, `is_prime(n)` takes less than a second, but `is_prime_sieve(n)` practically never ends! Did I wrote the sieve wrong?

My code is:

```
# determines if prime using trial division
def is_prime(n):
    d = {}
    u = math.floor(math.sqrt(n))
    i = 2
    # trial division: works pretty well for determining 600 billion
    while (i <= u):
        if (n % i == 0):
            return False
        i += 1
    return True

# primality test with sieve
def is_prime_sieve(n):
    # first find all prime numbers from 2 to u
    # then test them
    u = math.floor(math.sqrt(n))
    prime = {}
    lst = range(2, int(u)+1)
    for i in lst:
        j = 2
        prime[i] = True
        while (i*j <= u):
            prime[i*j] = False
            j += 1
    while (u >= 2):
        if (u not in prime) or (prime[u]):
            if (n % u == 0):
                return False
        u -= 1
    return True
```

Comment: FWIW: `return all(n % i for i in range(2, int(n**0.5)+1))`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the Sieve of Erastothenes you are recomputing the sieve every time. The sieve should be cached so that you only generate it once. It works well when you build the sieve once and then perform *many* primality checks; it is very inefficient if you only check a single number.

This means, by the way, that you need to anticipate the highest prime number and generate the sieve table up to that number.

When done right, `is_prime_sieve` becomes simply:

```
def is_prime_sieve(n):
    return prime[n]
```

You would not need the `while` loop.

Comment: I see that makes sense. So trial division is faster afterall, without cacheing. the sieve..

Comment: They do two different things: the sieve generates *all* prime numbers in a range, trial division determines if a single number is prime. Consider the running time of `filter(is_prime, range(N))` compared with `sieve(N)` to generate all primes from 1 to N.

Comment: "Trial division" isn't faster than the sieve when the sieve is used properly. However, for very large singular primality tests a variant of your presented trial division does exist. This variant only involves dividing by numbers which have been proven to be relevant toward particular ranges.

Answer (score 0):

The sieve finds *all* primes from 1 to n. Calculating *one* sieve is an awful lot faster than doing trial division for each of these numbers. Obviously if you determine *all* primes from 1 to n, and then throw away all the information for the first n-1 numbers, that's very inefficient.

It's like comparing the speed of a bus and a two seater sports car. The bus is much much faster if you need to take fifty people from A to B. If you take a single passenger, guess what, the sports car is faster.

Answer (score 0):

But even with the traditional method of building the sieve, there is still far too many transactions occurring.
I have developed a way of extracting prime numbers without division (except for data management purposes) adapting the basic sieve of Eratosthenes. I do not have to set any upper or lower bounds, the algorithm is completely open ended. I develop a data string from which I can go anywhere in the calculated range and pull up all the prime numbers in a subset range. I waste no calculations with division.

Comment: This does not answer the question. You are just speaking about your code without showing it.